# How can I use JavaScript to grab a random div?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using JavaScript to create a grid. What I'm trying to do is have a random box that is created change colors when I click on the "Play" button but I cannot seem to get it figured out.

I've tried using various amounts of Math.random(), this might be where my problem is.

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container');
const gameButton = document.createElement('button');


 // This is the button I'm trying to use for this.

gameButton.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    let getRandom = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
    
});


let userInput = prompt('Enter a number between 10-20: ');
if (isNaN(userInput)) {
    alert('Numbers only.');
    location.reload();
} else if (userInput < 10) {
    alert('That\'s less than 10');
    location.reload();
} else if (userInput > 20) {
    alert('That\'s greater than 20');
    location.reload();
} else {
    gameButton.textContent = 'Play';
    gameButton.style.height = '25px';
    gameButton.style.width = '50px';
    gameButton.style.borderRadius = '7px';
    gameButton.style.marginBottom = '15px';
    container.appendChild(gameButton);
}


for (let index = 1; index <= userInput; index++) {
    let gameBoard = document.createElement('div');
    gameBoard.setAttribute('class', 'game-board');
    container.appendChild(gameBoard);

    for (let j = 0; j < userInput; j++) {
        const square = document.createElement('div');
        square.setAttribute('class', 'square');
        gameBoard.appendChild(square);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
    </div>

    <!---<script src="./app.js"></script>--->
</body>
</html>
```

Expected result is one of the 'divs' changes color when the button is clicked on.

Comment: "I've tried using various amounts of Math.random(), this might be where my problem is."  Where?

Comment: Put it into a js fiddle.

Comment: Well personally I like to delete code that doesn't work.

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y568zx09/

I've been reading the mozilla docs about Math.random() but it's not really clicking with me.

Comment: I get what you're getting at. I'm just confused as to how the Math.random() function works without numbers. I can easily return some numbers between 2 integers, I just don't understand how to do it with html elements.

Comment: When you collect HTMLElements into a NodeList you can treat that list as if it were an array. Then, use the random number as the array index to pull out of the NodeList. You have the NodeList stored in `getRandom`; You should accept The Quodesmith answer.

Comment: Ok, i've updated your fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/y568zx09/  Try to press play and see if it's what you looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Between your question and your code, it's a little confusing. But just going off what you said, here's a way to choose a random element from a list of elements, provided you give it a class name (feel free to tweak this):

```
// Function to get a random number, taking in min and max values.
const randomNum = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)

// Function that takes in a class name to select all those elements
// on the page, and returns a random one from the list.
const getRandomElement = className => {
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll(`.${className}`)
  const num = randomNum(0, elements.length - 1)
  return elements[num]
}
```

Comment: @RandyCasburn Woops! Typo. Fixed.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Clearly I've not had enough coffee today -_-

Comment: Doesn't matter - this is an OP that has only accepted one answer out of the 6 Qs posed.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Sorry I wasn't aware of stackoverflow "etiquette" off of the 6 questions I've asked within the last 2 years. The last one being over a year ago.

Comment: @TheQodesmith thank you. I'm dissecting how this works now and will comment back with questions once I wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the code in your event listener like this:

```
gameButton.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    let divs = document.getElementsByClassName('game-board');
    let random_div = divs[Math.floor(Math.random()*divs.length)];
    random_div.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
});
```

Or if you want only one square to change color, use document.getElementsByClassName('square') instead.

Comment: Ok I think see what you're doing there. So from the docs,
`Math.floor` returns an integer of a number given. Then
`Math.random()` returns an integer of a range.
So you're returning an integer of the range of `divs.length`. Am I on the right track with that?

Comment: Yes. And by the way Math.random(), without any arguments, returns a decimal number between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

Relevante part o the code. You can make it better checking the elements, the styles, etc. But essentially it is:

```
gameButton.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    let getRandom = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
    var a = Math.random()
    let b = a.toString().substr(2, 1)
    getRandom[b].style = 'background-color: ' + (parseInt(b) % 2 == 0 ? 'yellow' : 'red')
});
```

So you use Math.Random to get some random number after the dot(.) and use it to read some index from the collection you get for the getRandom.
Then you just set element style or whatever you want.

The fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cm5kyrdj/